# C# Method not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I'm creating the following method that returns a normalized decimal value.  The AngleUnits is an enum that contains Degrees, Gradians, Radians, and Turns.  However after implementing this code I get "Angle.Normalize(...) not all code paths return a value".  Not sure what I'm missing here as I am returning the decimal value.  Thanks in advance.

```
private static decimal Normalize(decimal value, AngleUnits units)
    {
        decimal normalizedValue;

        switch (units)
        {
            case AngleUnits.Degrees:
                if (value >= 0 && value <= 360)
                {
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = value + 360;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value > 360)
                {
                    value = value - 360;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                break;

            case AngleUnits.Gradians:
                if (value >= 0 && value <= 400)
                {
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = value + 400;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value > 400)
                {
                    value = value - 400;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                break;

            case AngleUnits.Radians:
                if (value >= 0 && value <= twoPi)
                {
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = value + twoPi;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value > twoPi)
                {
                    value = value - twoPi;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                break;

            case AngleUnits.Turns:
                if (value >= 0 && value <= 1)
                {
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = value + 1;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value > 1)
                {
                    value = value - 1;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got this error because you can have a call to this method with an angleunits that has no match in the switch statement and your method should return a method  So the compiler is detecting this.

when you close your switch statement

you should `return  a default value`

or throw an exception

```
Throw new Exception("no units was found  ")
```

here a snippet of your method

```
  private static decimal Normalize(decimal value, AngleUnits units)
        {
            decimal normalizedValue;

            switch (units)
            {
                case AngleUnits.Degrees:
                    if (value >= 0 && value <= 360)
                    {
                        normalizedValue = value;
                        return normalizedValue;
                    }
                    else if (value < 0)
                    {
                        value = value + 360;
                        normalizedValue = value;
                        return normalizedValue;
                    }
                    else if (value > 360)
                    {
                        value = value - 360;
                        normalizedValue = value;
                        return normalizedValue;
                    }
                    break;

                default: throw new Exception("no Angleunits match was found");  






            }
            return value; 


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not handling the `default` case in the switch.

In the case when I am switch on an `enum` I like to throw an `InvalidEnumArgumentException` in the `default`. This ensures that if I add to the `enum` in the future and forget to update the switch statement I will fail fast.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is concerned about what will happen if the variable you are switching on does not match against any case that you provided. If that happens, no return statement will be hit. Try this to fix it:

```
private static decimal Normalize(decimal value, AngleUnits units)
    {
        decimal normalizedValue;

        switch (units)
        {
            case AngleUnits.Degrees:
                if (value >= 0 && value <= 360)
                {
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = value + 360;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value > 360)
                {
                    value = value - 360;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                break;

            case AngleUnits.Gradians:
                if (value >= 0 && value <= 400)
                {
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = value + 400;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value > 400)
                {
                    value = value - 400;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                break;

            case AngleUnits.Radians:
                if (value >= 0 && value <= twoPi)
                {
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = value + twoPi;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value > twoPi)
                {
                    value = value - twoPi;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                break;

            case AngleUnits.Turns:
                if (value >= 0 && value <= 1)
                {
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = value + 1;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                else if (value > 1)
                {
                    value = value - 1;
                    normalizedValue = value;
                    return normalizedValue;
                }
                break;
        }
        return null;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "default" value for the switch.
You are using an enumeration and that seem to limit the switch cases to only the values you have created for the enumeration, but that's not true, an enumeration is really stored in a numeric type, by default `int` but can be set as `byte` `short` or `long`. Then any number can be casted to an enum, even if it's outside the range of values you have defined for it, that's why you must handle the "default" value.